# Incorrect syntax must declare scalar variable

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, ms-access-2007

I am trying to copy the data from MS Access to a SQL Server database.

One of the columns has the name `Fill Pressure (psi)` which is causing a problem in SQL Server. I get the following error:

> "Incorrect syntax near "Psi" must declare the scalar variable @fill.

Code is as below

```
 Dim Cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
 Cmd.Connection = sqlConnection

 For Each dc As DataColumn In AccessTable.Columns
     colquery = colquery + "[" + dc.ColumnName + "],"
     valquery = valquery + "@" + dc.ColumnName + ","
     Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + dc.ColumnName, dr(dc.ColumnName))
 Next

 colquery = colquery.Substring(1, colquery.Length - 1)
 valquery = valquery.Substring(1, valquery.Length - 1)

 colquery = colquery + ")"
 valquery = valquery + ")"
 Sqlquery = colquery + valquery
 Sqlquery = Replace(Sqlquery, ",)", ")")

 Cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
 Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 Cmd.CommandText = Sqlquery

 Dim sqlcommand1 As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [" + TableName + "]  ON", sqlConnection)
 sqlcommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

 Dim sqlcommand2 As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [" + TableName + "] OFF", sqlConnection)
 sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The sample of the insert statement from the watch. I have already tried replacing the space and "(" and ")" with empty string but it is not working.

```
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblVesselTypes] ([VesselType_ID], [Manufacturer],[Model], [Fill Pressure (psi)], [Empty Weight (lbs)], [Full Weight (lbs)], [Liq Liters], [Type], [Size])
VALUES (@VesselType_ID, @Manufacturer, @Model, @Fill Pressure (psi), @Empty Weight (lbs), @Full Weight (lbs), @Liq Liters, @Type, @Size)"
```

Comment: The problem is the variable  `@Fill Pressure (psi)` and `@Empty Weight (lbs)` containing spaces and parenthesis.  Try stripping them out when you declare them/setup `valquery`

Comment: I have tried it already and didn't help. The query as below                                               INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tblVesselTypes] ([VesselType_ID],[Manufacturer],[Model],[Fill Pressure (psi)],[Empty Weight (lbs)],[Full Weight (lbs)],[Liq Liters],[Type],[Size])VALUES (@VesselType_ID,@Manufacturer,@Model,@FillPressurepsi,@EmptyWeightlbs,@FullWeightlbs,@LiqLiters,@Type,@Size)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to have variable with name like `@Fill Pressure (psi)` in MS Sql. SQL Server would parse if like `@Fill` is a variable name and `Pressure (psi)` is unknown command or type (for variable declaration) or something else - anyway error here.

See naming convention for different types of objects in MS SQL:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

Variable name cannot have spaces or brackets in it. While object names can be surrounded with square brackets or quotes.

Possible variable name for you is, for example: `@FillPressure_psi`

so whole insert statement would look like:

```
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblVesselTypes] ([VesselType_ID], [Manufacturer],[Model], [Fill Pressure (psi)], [Empty Weight (lbs)], [Full Weight (lbs)], [Liq Liters], [Type], [Size])
VALUES (@VesselType_ID, @Manufacturer, @Model, @FillPressure_psi, @EmptyWeight_lbs, @FullWeight_lbs, @Liq Liters, @Type, @Size)"
```

Comment: This one is still not working. Now I get an error saying "Syntax Error near Psi. Must declare the scalar variable @FillPressure_psi.

Comment: @dotnet how did you declare previous variables e.g. @Model?